# d3 fisheye undefined

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to use the d3 fisheye plugin.

But, I am getting this error: d3.fisheye is undefined

Which is strange.

```
//initialize fisheye
    var fisheye = d3.fisheye.circular()
        .radius(200)
        .distortion(2);

    this.chart.on("mousemove", function() {
      fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));
    });
```

I thought it might be because I was using d3.v2 but I updated it to d3.v3 and I am still having the same problem.
Is it even in that file. I do see a fisheye.js floating around at:
https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye
I am also kind of confused because there is absolutely no mention of fisheye in the API documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fisheye is a plugin, you need to include the file `fisheye.js` and the d3 library as well.